# Is there a way to make an IPython Notebook output interactivly create an input and execute it?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ipython-magic

I was wondering if I can make an output interactively run a piece of code. So if for example I had a class (parts in pseudo-code):

```
import numpy as np

class test(object):
    def __init__():
        self.a = np.random.randn(10)
        print ## Interactive Output: Click me to view data array##

    def show():
        print a
```

So when I create a class instance it should output some interactive link (maybe in html) or something like that and when I click it, the `show()` method should be called. However, I have no idea how to achieve that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the widgets shipped with the notebook (for [jupyter they are an independent package](https://github.com/ipython/ipywidgets)).

Something like this could do what you want (Python 3):

```
from IPython.html import widgets
from IPython.display import display
import numpy as np

class Test(object):
    def __init__(self, arraylen):
        self.a = np.random.randn(arraylen)
        self.button = widgets.Button(description = 'Show')
        self.button.on_click(self.show)
        display(self.button)

    def show(self, ev = None):
        display(self.a)
        self.button.disabled = True


test = Test(10)
```

- You create a button widget when you initialise the class `widgets.Button(description = 'Show')`
- Attach an event to it `button.on_click(self.show)`
- And display the button `display(self.button)`
- In the `show` method I included a way to disable the button functionality once the array is showed `self.button.disabled = True`. You can comment this line if you want to show more times the array.

Comment: Do you also know if I can arrange the buttons in a html table as well as the output?

Comment: You could use a combination of `widgets`, `display` and `HTML`. You should open a new question with what you need as ouput in order to others or I can provide a more accurate answer to this new requirement.

Comment: Please find the other question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32181126/how-to-align-widget-buttons-in-ipython-notebook)