# How to align widget buttons in IPython notebook

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I have the following peace of code

```
from ipywidgets import widgets
from IPython.display import display
import numpy as np

class Test(object):
    def __init__(self, arraylen):
        self.a = np.random.randn(arraylen)
        self.button = widgets.Button(description = 'Show')
        self.button.on_click(self.show)
        display(self.button)

        self.button1 = widgets.Button(description = 'Show1')
        self.button1.on_click(self.show)
        display(self.button1)

    def show(self, ev = None):
        np.savetxt('test',self.a)
        self.button.disabled = True


test = Test(10)
```

The output is two buttons in a column as shown here:
[image]

Would it also be possible, to embed the buttons in a HTML table (where I could choose them to be in a row), or any other organization scheme? Maybe it could look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could use (a very basic example):

```
from IPython.display import display
from ipywidgets import widgets
button1 = widgets.Button(description = 'Button1')
button2 = widgets.Button(description = 'Button2')
display(widgets.HBox((button1, button2)))
```

[Here](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/tree/master/examples/Interactive%20Widgets) you can find basic and more complete examples about the use of the widgets. If you are using Jupyter you should adapt some info (`from ipywidgets import widgets` instead `from IPython.html import widgets`,...).

Comment: and how do I display them?

Comment: I edited the code to include the `display`. If it is the last statement of your code cell it should be showed automatically, if not you should use `display`.

Comment: Do you also know a way to do that in arbitrary arrangements? Where for instance the position is given by a HTML cell?

Comment: You have some css attributes you can modify in order to adjust some stuff. For example, for the button instance I can see the following keys (e.g., `button1.keys`), some of them related with css: 
'border_width',
 'font_weight',
 '_model_module',
 'button_style',
 'border_radius',
 '_view_name',
 'msg_throttle',
 'margin',
 'width',
 'padding',
 'disabled',
 'height',
 'border_style',
 '_dom_classes',
 'color',
 'description',
 'border_color',
 'version',
 'visible',
 'tooltip',
 'font_family',
 '_model_name',
 'background_color',
 'font_size',
 'font_style',
 'icon'

Comment: And how to modify them? Would you mind to give a brief example?

Comment: Great! I think this will help! Thank you so much!

Comment: The widgets are now an independent repo after the IPythonJupyter split some months ago. The most updated info about how to use and import widgets can be found [here](https://github.com/ipython/ipywidgets/blob/master/examples/Index.ipynb).

Comment: http://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Widget%20Styling.html